# How to add header files in visual studio code for c++?

Tags: c++, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, header-files, eigen

I dont know how to use external library headers in visual studio code for c++. I wanted to use libraries like eigen matplotlib_cpp etc for my project. I used vcpkg for downloading and I added the path of the library in .json file

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include/python3.10",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include/numpy",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include/matplotlib-cpp"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.16299.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

But I end up with the error saying

```
HelloCheck.cpp:1:27: fatal error: matplotlibcpp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <matplotlibcpp.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
```

I also will mention my sample code below

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
int main() {
    matplotlibcpp::plot({1,3,2,4});
    matplotlibcpp::show();
}
```

And this is my task.json file

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [
                // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/t:build",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

I didnt get any clear answer to solve this issue. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

How will I add external library headers of c++ in visual studio code without any errors?

Comment: The `c_cpp_properties.json` file determines how Intellisense is handled, it's not used for the actual compilation. What are the contents of your `tasks.json` file?

Comment: I have added my task.json file . Can you solve my issue please